# FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD not working on Xiaomi phone

Tags: android, xiaomi

I am writing code in Android to display an activity on the locked screen. The activity has an activity button which launches another new activity. For the new activity, I have added FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD so that the activity can be showed on the lock screen. Ideally if the keyguard is currently active and is secure (requires an unlock credential) than the user can confirm it using the lock pattern or key code or whatever the user set and then the activity window should appear. It works as expected on all phones except the Xiaomi Phone - after clicking the button there is no prompt shown to the user to unlock. How can I resolve this issue?

Here is a snippet of my code:

I have this code in the `onActivityResumed(Activity activity`) method of the new activity:

```
final Window win = activity.getWindow();
win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

The new activity will be resumed on the button click and hence I have it in the `onActivityResumed` API.